# unable to connect to sql server using jmeter 5.1.1 version

Tags: mysql, jmeter

I'm unable to connect jmeter with sqlserver. Below mentioned are my configurations

**JDBC Connection Configuration**

[image: Below is my JDBC configuration]

**JDBC Request**

[image: This is my JDBC request]

**Results**
[image: Unable to connect]

**NOTE**

1)My firewall is off

2)I have added mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin in **lib** folder

3) I'm using Jmeter 5.1.1 version

Please help me to get out of this. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong driver and URL, you're using mysql driver classes instead of sql server ones.

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a Network problem linked to you Database. Just be sure you do not use Localhost in your Jmeter (If you do use 127.0.0.1 instead). If that is ok then the Jmeter configuration is correct.

Check #bind-address=127.0.0.1 in your mysql files.

Another thing to try is removing this attribute from the (Derby DB) resource tag
: validationQuery="select 1"